# How do individually controlled feather like winglets work?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, winglets

I want to know how the individually controlled feather like winglets work on controlling and rolling by reducing drag.(concept of airbus bird's of prey) 
I just need a detailed review of the aerodynamics and its mechanics and how it reduce drag and what are its effect on L/D ratio etc as i am a aeronautical student i wish to know more about it on the futuristic design so it can be helpful in my projects

Comment: I think the Airbus is doing research on this to answer the question of how much drag it reduces and how the effect on lift/drag ratio is. So probably nobody yet knows the answer to that.

Comment: *"I just need a detailed review of the aerodynamics and its mechanics"* wow!  :)

Comment: Please ask Airbus Marketing. Engineering will not be helpful in this – they still shake their heads about this concept.

Answer (score 1):

The "Bird of Prey" is nothing more than an artist's conception at this point so there is nothing to review from a mechanical design standpoint.

Somebody thought it would be neat to make a plane that looked like a bird, but the methods by which birds achieve flight is far different than in modern aircraft.  I don't believe there are any practical advantages to having a control surface that looks like a feather, and "function follows form" isn't a design strategy that has been proven to work.

I doubt we will ever see one fly, but it would make a fanciful sculpture, like this:

[image: Brad Story's "Roscoe"]